# How to manage source code and infra seprately with Terraform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have an app written in Nodejs, deployed to GCP AppEngine.
AppEngine configuration is defined in yaml file like this

```
# app.yaml
runtime: nodejs12

# instance class
instance_class: F4_1G

# environment variables
env_variables:
  ENVIRONMENT: 'develop'
```

AppEngine deploy command

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

From now on I want to manage this AppEngine infra with Terraform. How can I deploy separately Nodejs source (by gcloud) and yaml file (by Terraform) but app still working?
Any tutorial or related links is approciate.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [app_engine_application](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/app_engine_application) terraform resource.

If you really want to use gcloud, there is also [Terraform gcloud module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google/latest).

For example:

```
# Verify Terraform gcloud module works in your environment
module "gcloud_deploy_app" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google"
  version = "~> 2.0"
  use_tf_google_credentials_env_var = true
  skip_download                     = false

  create_cmd_entrypoint  = "gcloud"
  create_cmd_body        = "app deploy app.yaml"

  # if you want to skip the destroy, but you could also have another gcloud command
  destroy_cmd_entrypoint = "echo"
  destroy_cmd_body       = "skip"
}
```